# What is this menagerie doing in my bread-basket?

Tags: terminology

I have just been visiting the supermarket, and been bewildered by some of the products on offer. I have previously enjoyed *tiger bread*, which appears to be a long flat loaf with sesame oil on top.

I encountered a novelty this evening, though which was *giraffe bread*, the ingredients of which are unclear. It is long, but otherwise not all that reminiscent of a giraffe.

Could anyone refer me to a source to help me out with the meanings of these strange names? Are there others of this sort? Where should I look for a definitive list of bread names?

**Edit**, as Mark Beadles suggests: this shopping was done in the North-East of England. I didn't notice any tiger or giraffe meat being involved.

Comment: According to Google and Wikipedia, giraffe bread *is* tiger bread. Is yours not?

Comment: Knowing what part of the English-speaking world you're asking this about would be helpful. Here in the Midwest US these terms would imply bread made with tiger or giraffe meat. :/

Comment: @Mark Beadles - hey Mark, this is a cooking question. Be not criticism!

Comment: maybe this would be a better question for [cooking.stackexchange.com](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions)?

Comment: I have no idea what *giraffe bread* is, and I don't feel motivated to look it up right now. But I have complete confidence that if I *could* be bothered, I'd find the answer in seconds. This is General Reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here for a complete explanation of your cooking question: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-16812545

Also, I highly doubt that there is a 'definitive list' of bread. Everyday someone can add a name to this list.

Comment: funny :) makes me think about how germans put two words together to make a 'new' one with a different meaning. the word 'pineapple' comes to mind...what to pines have to do with apples/giraffes with bread ? seems to me the clue is in the pattern: pine cones have Fibonacci spirals as do pineapples...probably the dark/bright brown contrasted pattern on the surface of the bread looks similar to a giraffes one. If everyday someone can add a name, I'll be that someone today: reaction-diffusion bread B-)